# SSH Protocol V1 (Cannot log into my Dedicated Server)

Tags: 18.10

I have a dedi running 16.04 and I run 18.10 Desktop.

Today I am unable to log into my dedi, via SSH, as I get the following error

SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported

Hoping someone can please help me, or I have some serious problems.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, I run 18.10 on my personal computer.

Comment: You may want to keep your "dedi" updated.

Comment: Lesson learnt.  Luckily no harm done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place something like this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host sq
     Hostname squid
     User walt
     ForwardX11 yes
     Protocol 2
```

`ssh` protocol 1 is depreciated because it leaks info, and can be broken so that encrypted traffic can be viewed.